# How to solve font problem

Tags: fonts, arxiv

I have tried to submit an paper to arXiv, but have not completed due to the Chinese characters(data), the following is the help to solve the problem, but I cann't understand them completely, any body can give example for every steps?

> Defining a custom font mapping
>
> You can bundle non-standard or custom fonts with your submission and
>   instruct dvips to use an additional font map file, e.g. myfonts.map,
>   so that dvips is executed with the fontmap option: dvips
>   -u+./myfonts.map
>
> by adding a file called 00README.XXX to your submission with the
>   directive:
>
> myfonts.map fontmap
>
> which identifies your private font map file as a dvips fontmap. For
>   map file syntax consult the dvips info pages. Many font bundles from
>   CTAN come with their custom font map files, and you can use these as
>   is with this directive. The file name of the font map file must have
>   extension ".map" and it must consist of letters A-Z, a-z only.

The URL for help is http://arxiv.org/help/00README#fontmap

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Usually, we don't put a greeting or a “thank you” in our posts. While this might seem strange at first, it is not a sign of lack of politeness, but rather part of our trying to keep everything very concise. [Accepting and upvoting answers is the preferred way here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about) to say “thank you” to users who helped you.

Answer (score 1):

This is what worked for me. It worked for an upload to be processed with pdftex; I don't know if it'd work with a dvi-gs upload. Note that step **4.** below seems to be required since January 2017.

**0. Get ready:** Make sure that the fonts you want to use are correctly installed in your own TeX distribution (in your computer). Let's say that the font package is called *FFF*. Create a folder, say "*myupload*" where you'll put the files that you need to include with your arXiv upload.

**1. Find and copy the .fd files:** Your font package should have a *FFF*.sty file in your TeX distribution, typically in a directory that ends with

```
...\tex\latex\FFF\
```

For example, the package [Classico](https://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/fonts/urw/classico/) has a `classico.sty` file in the directory

```
\texlive\texmf-local\tex\latex\classico\
```

if you have a TeX-Live distribution. That directory should also contain a lot of .fd files. **Copy** (don't move) the .sty file and all the .fd files to your *myupload* directory.

**2. Find and copy the Metafont files:** In your TeX distribution you should also find a directory ending with

```
...\fonts
```

For example `\texlive\texmf-local\fonts` if you have a TeX-Live distribution. This directory contains the subdirectories `\tfm`, `\type1`, `\vf`, `\opentype`, `\pfm`, `\afm`, `\enc`, `\map`. Go recursively into *each one* of them. In *each* you should arrive at an `\FFF` subdirectory: **copy** all the files in that directory to your *myupload* directory.

For example, for Classico on a TeX-Live system you find

```
\texlive\texmf-local\fonts\tfm\urw\classico
```

which contains many .tfm files.
Very important, copy also the `FFF.map` file that you'll find in some subdirectory of `\fonts\map\`

Now your *myupload* folder should contain `FFF.sty`, `FFF.map`, and a lot of files ending in .fd, .tfm, and so on.

**3. Prepare the README file:** In the 00README.XXX file that you mention in your question, add the line

```
FFF.map fontmap
```

(*FFF*.map is the name of the file you previously found and copied).

**4. Fix the preamble of your .tex file:** (I recently discovered that the README file doesn't have any effect without this step.) In the .tex file of your submission add the line

```
\pdfmapfile{+FFF.map}
```

It should be the second line, with `\pdfoutput=1` as the first line.

**5. Upload:** Upload to arXiv your .tex file with all its dependencies, the 00README.XXX file, and all the files that you copied to your *myupload* directory. Best is to make a zip archive with all of them and upload that.

Fingers crossed. Hope this helps!